# Why can a variable be bound twice in a pattern?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Usually, F# does not allow pattern variables to occur twice in the same pattern. But in the following code, F# does not complain - is this a bug?

```
type foo = { A: int }
let test (x, {A = x}) = x
let result = test ("bla", {A = 3})
```

Comment: Simpler example - `let test (x,(x,y))=1`

Comment: Not sure why this question got a downvote - it looks like an interesting problem to me! I think this is a bug and you can report it by sending email to _fsbugs_ at _microsoft_ dot _com_.

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug - it's arguably following following scoping rules by binding to the closest defined x.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is a bug, although it seems confusing, but it's just the way the compiler compiles the above value binding.

Section 14.6.3 states that if the value definition is not a single value pattern (as is the case here), the elaborated expression is

```
tmp <typars1… typarsn> = expr
ident1 <typars1> = expr1
…
identn <typarsn> = exprn
```

where tmp is a fresh identifier and each expri results from the compilation of the pattern pat (§7) against input tmp [from [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819040)].

To see what the compiler does, we could use an F# quotation, e.g.:

```
<@ let test (x:int, {A = x:int})= x in test (3, {A = 5}) @>;;
```

In string format I get (leaving some stuff out):

```
Let (test,
     Lambda (tupledArg,
             Let (x, TupleGet (tupledArg, 0),
                  Let (_arg1, TupleGet (tupledArg, 1),
                       Let (x, PropertyGet (Some (_arg1), A, []), x)))),
     Application (test, NewTuple (Value (3), NewRecord (foo, Value (5)))))
```

which is why we get the "inner" x.

I don't think it's a bug but perhaps it would be more consistent if this would generate a warning.

Comment: Is this because shadowing  value names is allowed in F#?